# How to update local version of an updated Open Source App with git?

Tags: git, github

I have cloned [Apache Superset](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset) in 2019, and now want to update it. I have made local changes to the app (like in app.py or js files), so want to merge my local changes with the new release from Superset.

The problem is that the official Apache Superset Github source code is not my remote anymore, so I cannot just `git pull`.

Is there a way to do this in git?

PS: Don't know if relevant, but I'm running Superset with Docker. And the IDE I'm using is PyCharm.

Comment: would an option for example be to create a new branch, and merge my local code with the github code in it?

Comment: You can have several remotes (like one being called 'origin' and the other 'upstream'). Create another remote pointing to the repo you want to update from (called 'upstream') and do a `git pull upstream`.